# Django RestFramework returning a precomputed json

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

Currently I have this:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = (
            'id', 'f0', 'f1', 'f2')
```

And it returns something like this:

```
{
    "count": 6242,
    "previous": null,
    "total_pages": 209,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 63915,
            "f0": "Some stuff"
            .....
         },
        {
            "id": 63916,
            "f0": "Some other stuff"
            .....
         }....            

     ]
}
```

And this is good, but I noticed that serializing the data is actually quite expensive to do on the fly, so I would like to precompute it. So far I've managed to precompute it and store it in a jsonfield for my model, the problem is my API is now returning {'json_repersentation':{myold_response}}

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('json_representation',)
```

My question is, is it possible to change it so that it simply returns the json contained within json_representation field without the "overhead" of {'json_representation':{id:0, f0:label...}} and instead just simply {id:0, f0:label...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the serializer `to_representation` method:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = super(MySerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    return data['json_representation']
```

Comment: Ah! Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.